# Apply transform when hover on an image

Tags: css, css-transitions

guys! Sorry to bother you with what may be a very basic CSS issue, but I´m running out of clues here...

I have 6 images on screen. I want to make a zoom-in movement in the image I´m hover on. This is my HTML (just a couple of images, so the code is not so long):

And this is my CSS:

```
.container::after
{
    content: "";
    clear: both ;
    display: table;
}    

#img1
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    position: relative;
}

#img2
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    position: relative;
}

.container:hover #img1
{
    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
}

.container:hover #img2
{
    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
}

.bigThumb
{
  position: relative;   
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bigThumb:hover
{
 cursor: pointer;
}

.bigThumb:hover div{
 visibility: visible;
 opacity: 1; 
}
```

It does perform the zoom in, but
a. In all six images at the same time
b. It doesn´t recognize when I leave the current image (meaning it doesn´t return to the original scale, unless I leave the main container)

Thanks you very much, and sorry -again- for asking for what may be a very simple problem... I´ve spend half a day trying to solve this before asking here :-)

Comment: Please show your HTML, better still provide a [MCVE]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Jon, I did include the HTML code in the original msg, but after editing it, somw sentences of the message dissapeared (random words and sentences, don´t know why). Anyway, the wen won´t let me post another msg for 90 minutes, so I´ll try again tomorrow. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

your css is saying, on hover in the `container` class, scale the images `#img1` and `#img2`. I assume your html looks something like

```html
<div class="container">
  <img id="img1"/>
  <img id="img2"/>
</div>
```

If you want to scale each image individually, you will want to use a `child` css selector like so (with `>`) and add the hover selector to the image html element (better to use classes or html elements here):

```css
.container > img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
}
```

That css is saying, for any `img` tag that is being hovered over in the `container` class, transform it. (Note also the `:hover` is on the image not the container)

Comment: Thanks, Bryce S! I´ll publish the HTML and the CSS files now